# Left side steering wheels in "MI: Dead Reckoning"?

Tags: realism, mission-impossible

In the new *Mission Impossible* movie, all the vehicles, even distinctly European ones, have American (left side) steering wheels. Why is that?

Comment: You do realize there's but *one single* country in the entirety of Europe that uses "non-American" steering wheel placement, right? If not, I'm afraid the premise of the question is based on confusion entirely unrelated to the topic of movies & TV. If yes, please elaborate why you think the steering wheels should be placed any differently.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Actually, there are at least four depending on how you count it. Actual countries: UK, Malta, Cyprus and Ireland. Also, the Crown Dependencies of The Isle of Man and The Channel Islands.

Comment: @Darren Okay, I genuinely forgot Ireland. ;-) It would nevertheless be helpful context if the question could elaborate that the majority of the plot is set in Malta or the Bailiwick of Guernsey.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like all of the settings in the movie are in places where cars are driven on the right side of the road. In those places, the steering wheel is on the left.

I’m not sure why you say "even the European ones", because it looks like every single mainland European country has right side driving and left side steering wheels.

I would go as far as to say that it doesn’t make sense to call left side steering wheels “American", since over 2/3 of all countries use left side steering wheels, and most of the countries with right side steering wheels are formers British colonies. So it might make sense to call right side steering wheels "British" more than calling left side "American".

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-_and_right-hand_traffic